# How do I add post of an array to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

So this has been bugging me for quite a while...
I've been trying to add $_POST of an array to another array and it doesn't seem to work...

That's the input form :

```
<input name="camp[]" type="text" value="">

$NrCampuri = array();
$NrCampuri = $_POST['camp'];
```

That's the current form that I have.

What I aim to do is to assign the `$NrCampuri[0]` the post of the `camp[0]`.
I tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. I have multiple values in camp but I want to assign them one by one.

Comment: array_merge($NrCampuri ,$_POST['camp']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple use `array_merge`  function `merges` one or more arrays into `one array`

```
array_merge($NrCampuri ,$_POST['camp']);
```

As per your comment you need to use `array_push` for pushing specific values into new array .

```
array_push($NrCampuri,$_POST['camp'][0]); 
array_push($NrCampuri,$_POST['camp'][2]);
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want every value from camp transfered to $NrCampuri. I may want camp[0] or/and camp[2] only.

Comment: so you need array push like this array_push($NrCampuri,$NrCampuri[0]); array_push($NrCampuri,$NrCampuri[2])

Answer (score 0):

try this

$output = array_combine($NrCampuri, $_POST['camp']);